# How do we get the difference of two $n \times n$ matrix as $n^2 \times n^2$

Tags: matrices, graph-theory

So while going through the [paper](https://www.dropbox.com/s/428pyq6lek1tfax/WeightedGraphMatchingApproach.pdf?dl=0) H. A. Almohamad and S. O. Duffuaa: *[A Linear Programming Approach for the Weighted Graph Matching Problem](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22linear%20programming%20approach%22%20%22weighted%20graph%20matching%22)*, [DOI:10.1109/34.211474](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/34.211474). I came across the equation
[Equation (7) being transformed to Equation (10).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7LZX.png) I don't seem to know how they achieved that and what it means.

$$R=A_GP-PA_H \tag{7}$$

$$VEC(R)=A_{GH} VEC(P) \tag{10}$$

P- is an orthogonal matrix $n \times n$

A<sub>G</sub> and A<sub>H</sub> are Adjacency matrices

Comment: @Jerry Sangma You should consider the $n\times n$ matrix as a $n^2$-dimensional vector

Comment: @RobertZ So A<sub>GH</sub> is simply A<sub>G</sub> minus A<sub>H</sub> ?

Comment: @JerrySangma [Reference on how to type equations on this website](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). You can use `$A_{GH}$` for $A_{GH}$ for example.

Comment: @FrenzyLi thanks

Comment: @Jerry Sangma (7) is a set of linear relations between the $n^2$ components of $P$ and the $n^2$ components of $R$. So there is a matrix $A_{GH}$ that represents such relations. Try a small example, say $n=2$, to find how $A_{GH}$ comes from $A_{G}$ and $A_{H}$.

Comment: @RobertZ sorry i couldnt dedcue

Comment: @Jerry Sangma See below for a complete description of the matrix $A_{GH}$. I hope that this long discussion has been useful.

Answer (score 1):

Equation (7) is a set of linear relations between the $n^2$ components of $P$ and the $n^2$ components of $R$. So there is a $n^2\times n^2$ matrix $A_{GH}$ which represents such relations.

Let's see what happens for $n=2$.
If $A_G=\begin{bmatrix}
g_{11} & g_{12} \\ g_{21} & g_{22}\end{bmatrix}$ and $A_H=\begin{bmatrix}
h_{11} & h_{12} \\ h_{21} & h_{22}\end{bmatrix}$
and $VEC(P)=[p_{11}, p_{21}, p_{12}, p_{22}]^t$. Then from (7) and (10) we obtain:
$$A_{GH}=\left[\begin{array}{cc|cc}
(g_{11}-h_{11}) &g_{12} &-h_{21} & 0\\
 g_{21} &(g_{22}-h_{11}) &0 & -h_{21}\\
\hline
-h_{12} &0 &(g_{11}-h_{22}) & g_{12}\\
 0 &-h_{12} & g_{21} & (g_{22}-h_{22})\end{array}\right]$$
In general $A_{GH}$ is made of $n^2$ blocks $B_{ij}$ for $i=1,\dots,n$ and $j=1,\dots,n$: 
$$\mbox{$B_{ii}=A_G-h_{ii}$, and $B_{ij}=-h_{ji}\cdot I_{n\times n}$ for $i\not=j$.}$$

Comment: why $$A_{G} - A_{H} $$is not equal to: 
$$
        A_{GH}=\begin{bmatrix}
(g_{11}-h_{11}) &(g_{12}-h_{12})\\
(g_{21}-h_{21}) &(g_{22}-h_{22})\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: @Jerry Sangma $A_{GH}\not=A_G-A_H$. $A_{GH}$ is a $n^2\times n^2$ matrix, $A_G-A_H$ is a $n\times n$ matrix.

Comment: But isnt that how we substract two matrices?

Comment: @Jerry Sangma It is true that
$$A_{G}-A_H=\begin{bmatrix} (g_{11}-h_{11}) &(g_{12}-h_{12})\\ (g_{21}-h_{21}) &(g_{22}-h_{22})\end{bmatrix}$$
It is not true that $A_{GH}=A_G-A_H$.

Comment: At first $$A_{G} A_{H}$$ are both n x n matrices
so , $$
R=A_GP-PA_H \\
R=(A_G-A_H)P
$$
is it wrong?

Comment: @Jerry Sangma Yes it is wrong $P A_H\not=A_H P$ in general.

Comment: I appreciate u trying to help. But m starting from (7) to (10) trying to deduce how we ended up with $$ A_{GH} from R=A_GP-PA_H $$

Comment: @Jerry Sangma It can not be deduced with the usual algebraic operations of matrices. If you manipulate $A_G$, $A_H$ and $P$ you will always obtain a $n\times n$ matrix. The author defines $A_{GH}$ in the way I showed you and it is a $n^2\times n^2$ matrix.

Comment: ,let me go thru it all and see if i can understand .. thanks